# How to make the difference between the values of an array as minimal as possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given an array `A` of integers `N`, and after inputting the integers into the array, I need to make the difference between the neighboring less or equal to `D` and we need to do that in minimal moves. In the end print out the sum of the numbers that have been added or subtracted.
`For every 0 < i < N, |S[i] - S[i - 1]| <= D`
`You can increase and decrease the number of the array element`

Example 1: If we have an array like this
`N = 7, D = 3` `[2, 10, 2, 6, 4, 3, 3]`, then in this array we have to make the difference between the neighboring elements less or equal than 3. We don't modify the first array element, we skip over to the second array elements where we modify it from 10 down to 5 (since A[0] + 3 = 5), then we don't change the third element, we change the fourth element from 6 down to 5 (because A[3] + 3 = 5) and we don't change the rest of the elements because the difference between them is less than `D`. In the end we have to print out 6 (s = 0; 10 -> 5, s = 5; 6 -> 5, s = 6)

Example 2: If we have an array like this
`N = 7, D = 0` `[1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2]`. Since `D` in this case is 0, by some logic we have to make all of the numbers the same. The most optimal (and in the fewest steps to solve this) way is we start with the last elements, we leave A[6] and A[5], we skip over to A[4]. Since A[4] is 4 and A[5] is 2, we have to change the 4 down to 2. Now since A[4] is 2, we skip over A[3] and we go to A[3] we change it from 1 up to 2. Then we change A[1] from 4 down to 2 and in the end, we change A[0] from 1 up to 2. In the end we have to print out 6 (s = 0; 4 -> 2, s = 2; 1 -> 2, s = 3; 4 -> 2, s = 5; 1 -> 2, s = 6).

Some other test cases:

1. `N = 7, D = 1` `[2, 10, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3]` Solution: 10
2. `N = 5, D = 1` `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` Solution: 0

I am unable to find an algorithm or an approach to this problem. I have tried several solutions and the closest I have come to solving it was 7/30 test cases.
My code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, d, s1 = 0, s2 = 1;
    cin >> n >> d;

    int a[n], b[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        b[i] = a[i];
    }

    reverse(b, b + n);

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(a[i] - a[i - 1] <= d) {
            continue;
        } else {
            if(a[i] > a[i - 1] + d) {
                while(a[i] > a[i - 1] + d) {
                    a[i]--;
                    s1++;
                }
            } else if(a[i - 1] - d > a[i]) {
                while(a[i - 1] - d > a[i]) {
                    a[i]++;
                    s1++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(b[i] - b[i - 1] <= d) {
            continue;
        } else {
            if(b[i] > b[i - 1] + d) {
                while(b[i] > b[i - 1] + d) {
                    b[i]--;
                    s2++;
                }
            } else if(b[i - 1] - d > b[i]) {
                while(b[i - 1] - d > b[i]) {
                    b[i]++;
                    s2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(s1 >= s2)
        cout << s2;
    else
        cout << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What test case fails?  What output is expected?  What output do you get?

Comment: Test case ```N = 10, D = 1, [1 0 2 4 3 2 2 0 0 4 2]```. I get 3 instead of 6.
Since I have 2 arrays (One is arranging from the back, one from the front), this is what I got:
```A: 0 1 2 3 2 2 0 0 1 2    S = 6```
```B: 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 4 2 0    S = 3```
But as you can see, both of these are wrong, since on goes: 2, 2, 0, 0 and since D = 1, that can't happen. And the other goes: 2, 3, 0, 0

Comment: Please edit your post to include that information about the failing testcase. Also, is there an original source for this question with more details about the constraints?

Comment: It's in Macedonian, ```https://mendo.mk/Task.do?id=886```, but I think you can translate it easily with Google Translate.

Comment: It sort-of reminds me of [shell sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort).